Edge-Justify text and buttons in view
I'm very new to swift and trying to align text and buttons to the left/right edges, or at least have the buttons in a vertical column. Target is a MacOS app.
Like this:

(Even better if the folder names, eg "raw_files" are aligned in column)
I've been searching for hours and tried Forms, LabeledContent, adding .frame(width:alignment) to various places but no luck.
I could get the buttons to align horizontally but the text labels are right justified:

Adding .frame() to the Text item gives an error "Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure"
        Form
        {
            LabeledContent 
            {
                Button("Set")
                { }
            } label: {
                Text("Destination Folder: bobo")
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)
            }
            
            LabeledContent
            {
                Button("Reset")
                { }
            } label: {
                Text("Source: <none>")
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)

            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300)

This shouldn't be that hard.  Any suggestions on how to do it?
EDIT I
Sorry, my bad on the .left vs .leading.  I've changed the code but the text labels are still right justified


I believe you want .leading instead of .left for alignment. i.e.: .frame(alignment: .leading). Look at the image here for options: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alignment

Use Grid. Result:

Code:
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Grid {
            GridRow {
                // Note that gridColumnAlignment only needs to be used
                // on one cell in each column, and applies to all cells
                // in the same column.
                Text("Source Folder:")
                    .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                Text("raw_files")
                    .gridColumnAlignment(.leading)
                Button("Set") { }
                    .gridColumnAlignment(.center)
            }
            GridRow {
                Text("Destination Folder:")
                Text("raw_files")
                Button("Set") { }
            }
            GridRow {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0)

                Button("Run") { }
                    .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .border(Color.primary)
        .padding()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(MyView())


.left is not a valid option. Try .leading

See the options here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alignment
